# How to use Rust futures in callbacks?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, callback, future

Is there any way to use futures in callbacks?  For example...

```rust
// Send message on multiple channels while removing ones that are closed.

use smol::channel::Sender;

...

// (expecting bool, found opaque type)
vec_of_sender.retain( |sender| async {
  sender.send(msg.clone()).await.is_ok()
});
```

My work-around is to loop twice: On the first pass I delete closed senders (non-async) and on the second I do the actual send (async using `for sender in ...`).  But it seems like I should be able to do it all in a single `retain()` call.

Comment: Could you expand your example a bit, to include a [reprex]? Async code is very affected by the code around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `retain` in this way. The closure that `retain` accepts must implement `FnMut(&T) -> bool`, but every `async` function returns an implementation of `Future`.

You can turn an async function into a synchronous one by blocking on it. For example, if you were using `tokio`, you could do this:

```
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

vec_of_sender.retain(|sender| {
    rt.block_on(async { sender.send().await.is_ok() })
});
```

However, there is overhead to adding an async runtime, and I have a feeling that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

The closure passed to `retain` must return a `bool`, but every `async` function returns `impl Future`. Instead, you can use `Stream`, which is the asynchronous version of `Iterator`. You can convert the vector into a `Stream`:

```rust
let stream = stream::iter(vec_of_sender);
```

And then use the `filter` method, which accepts an asynchronous closure and returns a new `Stream`:

```
let vec_of_sender = stream.filter(|sender| async {
    sender.send(msg.clone()).await.is_ok()
}).collect::<Vec<Sender>>();
```

Comment: Where does `stream::iter` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating a new `Vec`, you can also use [`swap_remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove):

```
let mut i = 0usize;
while i < vec_of_sender.len() {
    if vec_of_sender[i].send(msg.clone()).await.is_ok() {
        i += 1;
    } else {
        vec_of_sender.swap_remove(i);
    }
}
```

Note that this will change the order of the vector.